# How do you get an INTEGER in a textfile mixed with Strings and Integer?

Tags: c

I'm trying to get an `int` value from a text file.
This is my current read file algorithm:

```
if (q) 
{
    while ((ch = fgetc(q)) != EOF)
    {
        if(ch == )
            printf("%c",ch);
    }
}
else
{
    printf("Failed to open the file\n");
}
```

Inside my text-file:

```
Occupant's Name: qwe qwe
Room Number: 1
Occupant's Category: Superior Double

Occupant's Name: h j
Room Number: 1
Occupant's Category: Superior Double

Occupant's Name: h j
Room Number: 1
Occupant's Category: Superior Double
```

I would like to get every room number.

Comment: Look into `fscanf`.

Comment: I see no attempt to read an integer here.

Comment: thanks guys..got it already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using fgets to read each line and sscanf to parse the line. This sscanf will fail on the lines that do not start with "Room Number:".

```
char line[100] = "";
int room = 0;
if (q) 
{
    while (( fgets ( line, sizeof line, q)))
    {
        if( ( sscanf ( line, "Room Number:%d", &room)) == 1) {
            printf("room number is %d\n", room);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    printf("Failed to open the file\n");
}
```